# Can I read multiple tables from salesforce in mule esb

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

How can I read multiple tables from salesforce?
Can I use groovy script? Or Salesforce connector provide to facility reading multiple tables??
Is there any other way ??

Answer (score 0):

The SFDC connector supports Salesforce Query language (SOQL). 
It's similar to SQL but it has it's limitations, JOINS are one of them. 
SOQL does offers a way to query more than one table at the time by using relationship queries, it may not always be what you need but it get's you closer.

Please take a look at SFDC documentation, http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Again this language works with the SFDC connector so if you need more information about it you'll be better of asking in a SFDC forum ;)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `Native query language` instead of `Datasense query Language` in your salesforce connector for query.